# Upload set of images to net core server from Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What's the best way to upload a set of images to a net core API?

For example, I'm trying to upload an object with details for a profile (name, other details, images).

Normally, I would simply send the entire object at once with a list of array of bytes for the images inside that object.

Is that the correct way of doing it?

Pseudo object:

```
ProfileEditRequest 
    Email : string
    Name : string
    Images : List<byte[]>


//POST: api/profiles/edit
[HttpPost("edit")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromBody]ProfileEditRequest profile)
{

}
```

I'm trying to use a single request, but of course if not possible I can send each image separately.

Comment: Did you try it? It seems like that would be just fine by looking at your code

Comment: Not yet, I'm still implementing the authentication. So I'm making sure that I'm following the right path.

Comment: it's not recommanded as big files can cause memory problems on your server.  Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2#uploading-large-files-with-streaming

Comment: I could not find an example there to upload the data (from the client side). Using multipart data.

Comment: You could change the `List<byte[]> Images` to `List<IFormFile>`  so that you will be able to bind the files manually.

Comment: Isn't that going to block the server? Isn't a MultiPartContent more suited for this task?